# SP 2013 - Workflow - anyone in group can approve

Tags: sharepoint-2013, workflow, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

In SharePoint designer 2013 workflow, 'Start assign a task process' is assigned to group and if group member approves it.. it getting approved and status also changing as complete but it is not moving to next stage.. 
Below are the setting
1)Completion criteria is set as "Wait for first response"
2)Expandgroup is "No"
3)Parallel assign - all at once
4)Also there is only one person in group(will increase in future)
Also i tried logging outcome value, its not getting logged in WF history
What I'm missing here ? please advise

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this, I was assigning to Sharepoint group earlier, now I created domain group and assigned it.. it works.